# How do you determine spells a dragon can cast?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, monsters

Trying to build a dragon and reading the description in the monster manual it says "The dragon knows and casts arcane spells as a sorcerer of the level indicated in its variety description, gaining bonus spells for a high Charisma score. Some dragons can also cast spells from the cleric list or cleric domain lists as arcane spells."

Where is this level indicated? Is it in the level adjustment section of the dragon description? Which for a black dragon reads "Level Adjustment: Wyrmling +3; very young +3; young +3; juvenile +4; others —" If so does a wyrmling get spells as a lvl 2 sorceror or a lvl 1+3=4?

Alternatively is it simply the dragons HD? Normally I would think this would indicate the "level" of a creature. But since the description specifically says level...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A dragon's effective-sorcerer-level is listed as "caster level" in the dragon's "abilities by age" table.

A black wyrmling can't cast spells at all. Black dragons first get casting at young adult age, at which point they have 16HD but only caster level 1.